# React Google Maps custom marker rotation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am trying to add a custom marker in React Google Maps and have each marker rotate based on the direction that the item is heading on the road.

I am able to make the rotation work when I use `path` for an svg instead of a `url` referencing an image. The problem with `path` is that I cannot get `fillColor` to work, only `strokeColor`. It would also be nice to have a complex shape and `path` is somewhat restricting in the type of shape that you can add to it, because cannot pass multiple paths into the string.

Please note that `heading` is getting the proper direction via my api and I have verified that it works.

Here is my current code, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
const createIcon = (heading) => ({
    width: '15px',
    url: 
 'my image path',
    rotation: heading || 0, // set the rotation prop to indicate direction
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a <\Marker> component being rendered? This is what I was able to get working for rotating a Marker. No issues with fillColor either.

```
render() {
    return <Marker
        position={{ lat: this.state.longitude, lng: this.state.latitude }}
        icon={
            {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scale: 3,
                strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
                fillColor: "#0000FF",
                fillOpacity: 1,
                rotation: 215
            }
        }
    />
}
```

Comment: should probably add, if you're on react-google-maps right now, you should probably switch over to react-google-maps/api https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api